# How would I use a button w/onClick to change a value that is here used in a useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to be able to change what is the "feed" in this with a button, not having to swap to a new page. I have the two values, with the "home" being the one that shows all blogs, and personal being just the ones with the author value of "mario". What would I have to do add to have the button onClick switch to using the personal filtered blogs. (and defaulting to the home, and if needed a button that changes the current listed blogs back to the home)

(I apologize for any like, poor conventions or anything, I am new to javascript, and well it is javascript)

```
    const Home = () => {
        const [viewCount, setViewCount] = useState(0);
        const {data: blogs, isPending } = useFetch();
        const history = useHistory();
        const [newBlog, setNewBlog] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(() => {
        const getNewBlog = async () => {
            const home = blogs
            const personal = blogs.filter((blog) => blog.author === 'mario')
            setNewBlog(home)
        }
            getNewBlog()
        },[]);

        return (
            <div className="home">
                <div className="profile">
                    <h2>Hello, User!</h2>
                    <div className="profile-picture">&nbsp;</div>
                        <p>Profile Views: {Math.round(viewCount / 2)}</p>
                        <a href="/">
                        <button onClick={null}>Manage Your Blog</button> // <-- the onClick that I mention
                        </a>
                </div>
                <div className="feed">
                    {isPending && <div>Loading... </div>}
                    { blogs && <BlogList blogs={newBlog} title = "Your Feed"/> }

                 </div>
           
            
            </div>

        
        );
    }
```

This isn't the full extent of what I have tried, I tinkered with some other stuff but looking back at it I was going at it with poor logic.

To cover what is expected to happen:

The default "feed" shows all blogs, onClick of the button, it switches over to just the blogs of the author 'mario'. Returning to the default feed could be done through another button, or just a refresh of page.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add one line in order to filter the blogs on click.

```
<button onClick={()=>setNewBlog([...blogs.filter((blog) => blog.author === 'mario')])}>Manage Your Blog</button>
```

I hope this helps, or comment if your expectation is different

Comment: Thank you, it does work, at first. But once I click the manage blog buttons it briefly shows the correct blogs in the feed, but the site then refreshes and leaves it blank. It seems to be defaulting to no blogs which is odd. If you need to see more of the code to fix it, let me know, thank you.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add codesandbox ?

Comment: I'm using replit for this assignment (I am aware of its performance and overall poor IDE), I could add to you to give access.